# Deitel Java Exercise 11 Edition 14.8

Tags: java

Please I need your help to answer the below question correctly. I've used my little experience to answer the question, but not exactly what the question required.

14.8 (Tokenizing Telephone Numbers) Write an application that inputs a telephone number as a string in the form (555) 555-5555. The application should use String method split to extract the area code as a token, the first three digits of the phone number as a token and the last four digits of the phone number as a token. The seven digits of the phone number should be concatenated into one string. Both the area code and the phone number should be printed. Remember that you’ll have to change delimiter characters during the tokenization process.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tokenizing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        String val = String.valueOf(num);
        String[] san = val.split("");
        for(int i = 0; i < san.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(san[i]);
            if(i == 2)
                System.out.print("-");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Answer (score 0):

This might work, except you can't read a string as an integer: there will be a runtime error if you enter parens, etc. You will have to fix the input logic.
You need to execute 2 split methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tokenizing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        String val = String.valueOf(num);
        String[] san = val.split(" "); // Split on the space
        // san[0] now has the area code, with the parens
        String areaCode = san[0].substring(1, 4);
        // areaCode now has the area code with parens removed
        // san[1] now has the xxx-yyyy part
        String[] san1 = san[1].split("-");
        // san1[0] now has the xxx part
        // san1[1] now has the yyyy part

    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to read string as an integer in this case? I see no need whatsoever

Comment: I agree. OP was reading it as an integer. I was working from that premise.